How to Import Excel Data with Specific Column as Quantity in Mathematica
I'm working on importing an Excel file into Mathematica and have a specific requirement for one of the columns. The data frame I'm importing contains a column named 'Hours', which I need to import as a quantity representing hours. I'm attempting to use SemanticImport for this task, but I'm facing difficulties specifying the 'Hours' column as a quantity.
Here's the approach I've tried:
SemanticImport["Path\\To\\File.xlsx", {"String", "String", "Hours"}, "NamedColumns", HeaderLines -> 1]

This code snippet is supposed to import the first two columns as strings and the 'Hours' column as a quantity. However, Mathematica does not seem to recognize "Hours" as a valid type for SemanticImport. According to Mathematica's documentation, there are specific data types like String, Number, Integer, etc., that SemanticImport recognizes, along with an Interpreter function for more complex data interpretations. However, integrating Interpreter within SemanticImport for the 'Hours' column has been challenging.

How can I specify the 'Hours' column to be imported as a quantity representing hours using SemanticImport
Is there a syntax or method to integrate Interpreter with SemanticImport for specifying complex data types, such as quantities with units? Any examples or guidance on how to correctly use SemanticImport for this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried:

Importing without specific type enforcement and then attempting to manually convert the 'Hours' column using Map and Quantity.
Searching for ways to use Interpreter within the SemanticImport command to specify the 'Hours' column as a quantity.

